# How do I add users automatically to groups as they register on a UserRegister form which inherits from a UserCreation form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, python-3.7, django-authentication

I am trying to add a user to groups that I have created in the django admin. How do I implement my view function so that the user is added to a group on registration?

I have created a custom UserRegisterform as illustrated below to so that users can indicate Group they are in. I have a problem with implementing my view function so that the users are automatically added to groups

I have researched and found this links :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/
https://www.guguweb.com/2014/09/10/group-combo-box-django-user-profile-form/

have created a form as follows:
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group,User


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'group']
```

my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for value in form.cleaned_data['group']:
                group = Group.objects.get(name= value)
                group.user_set.add(user)
            form.save()
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

when I log into the admin site, i expect to see the user assigned to the group he/she chose. The User is added but not assigned a group

Answer (score 2):

it worked. the solution to this, I refactored my views as follows:
views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from .forms import UserRegisterForm

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            group = form.cleaned_data['group']        
            group.user_set.add(user)
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django we have two ways to do add new users to groups, one is Function based on views and the second is Class-based views.

Points to remember:
**The primary key values that you will add with the group, should be integer only.**
Or you have to make sure that all the columns in related tables for groups will have character(varchar) data type. By default, it's an integer data type. I prefer to go with integer only.

You can do easily with function based views:

```
    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                group = form.cleaned_data['group']        
                group.user_set.add(user)
                #group.user_set.add(user.id) #if data in user is not of int, then use id with that to get primary int value. Else no need
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

In class-based views, after saving the value in DB, at the same pick the ID using the current user and save it to related to the group.

Second Class-based view:

```
    class UserCreationView():
        pass
        def form_valid(self, form):
            group = Group.objects.get(group_name)
            self.object = form.save()
            user_id = User.objects.values('id').filter(username=self.object)
            group.user_set.add(user_id)
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

#django #django-forms #django_groups #python

Answer (score 0):

You add user to group, but this user is not ready(by ready I mean saved in database). User is saved to database by `form.save()`. Call `form.save()` just before for loop. And give me feedback

Comment: I have tried that. This is the errors I get:TypeError at /register/
'Group' object is not iterable
. But the user is added when I check at the admin site

Comment: And the second problem is, that `form.cleaned_data['group']` return only one element, and you try to iterate over it - you get `'Group' object is not iterable`

Comment: @NYAME and is ok after that change?

Comment: still can't add a user to the group automatically. I have to manually add in the admin site. How can I reconfigure my views so that the user is added automatically since looping over form.cleaned_data['group'] is not viable?

Comment: form field for specifying group, should allow selecting multiple groups